# Create an alarm on tvOS with Swift

Tags: swift, tvos

How can I get an event to schedule for execution at a particular time of day using tVOS  since it does not use UILocalNotification / alarm /reminder or EventKit?

I just basically want a few events to happen when the app is in the foreground at a particular time of day via some sort of scheduling at a particular time of the day for tVOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up calculating the time difference between now and the time to schedule and run a performSelectorAfterDelay on the custom methods that need to be launched at the scheduled time provided the app is running in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed UILocalNotification, and push notifications are not currently supported on tvOS. There are also very few viable alternatives.

[This post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17855) talks about using WebSockets. Can't guarantee this will work, as I haven't tried it.

Here is [another link](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) to the notifications programming guide on Apple's API page. Again, nothing concrete that will produce a scheduled notification.